# Mouse drag direction tolerance

Tags: c#, input, unity-game-engine, mouse, game-engine

I'm working on a 2D game where the player can drag tiles around. It works in a way that the player clicks and hold a tile and depending in which direction the player moves the mouse from then on, the drag direction is decided.

The problem however is that this is overly sensitive. It might often be the case that the player starts dragging and wanted to drag vertically but due to the mouse sensitivity it turns out to drag horizontally (or vice versa).

Does anyone have an idea how to add a tolerance threshold to this dragging behavior? The relevant part in my code looks basically like this:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (_isMouseDown && sourceTile != null)
    {
        _isDraggingTile = true;

        /* Determine drag direction and drag target cell. */
        Vector3 dragDistance = Input.mousePosition - _originMousePosition;
        dragDistance.Normalize();
        if (_dragDirection == DragDirection.None)
        {
            float f = Vector3.Dot(dragDistance, Vector3.up);

            /* Mouse up drag. */
            if (f >= 0.5f)
            {
                _dragDirection = DragDirection.Up;
                _dragTargetCell = sourceTile.gridCell.upNeighbor;
            }
            /* Mouse down drag. */
            else if (f <= -0.5f)
            {
                _dragDirection = DragDirection.Down;
                _dragTargetCell = sourceTile.gridCell.downNeighbor;
            }
            else
            {
                /* Mouse right drag. */
                f = Vector3.Dot(dragDistance, Vector3.right);
                if (f >= 0.5f)
                {
                    _dragDirection = DragDirection.Right;
                    _dragTargetCell = sourceTile.gridCell.rightNeighbor;
                }
                /* Mouse left drag. */
                else if (f < -0.5f)
                {
                    _dragDirection = DragDirection.Left;
                    _dragTargetCell = sourceTile.gridCell.leftNeighbor;
                }
            }
        }

        if (_dragTargetCell != null)
        {
            // Take care of moving the dragged tile!
        }
    }
}
```

Simply delaying the calculation of `dragDistance` by some frames doesn't turn out to work very well. I think what is needed is a solution to figure out the mouse movement and decide on which axes it moves farthest. Determining the drag direction as above will probably never work out well.

Comment: First I would not use 0.5f as checking value. 0.78f (PI/4) is more appropriate since it represents 45 degrees. That would then cut your circle in four quadrants.

Comment: using 0.78 does indeed improve the direction determination. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with any collection of information is noise. In your case, the noise is defined by the wrong movement of the user. Nonetheless, it should be possible to minimize the effect of noise by averaging the values.

There are advanced algorithms used in DSP but I guess a basic averaging of the info should do in your case.

What you could try is that instead of moving in Update at once like you do, collect movement over several frames, then average all those frames and see if it goes better:

```
IEnumerator GetAverageMovement(Action<Vector3> result)
{
    int frames = 0; 
    List<Vector3>list = new List<Vector3>();
    while(frames < 30f) // half a second appr
    {
        list.Add(GetDirection());
        frames++;
        yield return null;
    }
    result(AverageAllValues()); 
}
```

GetDirection is just returning the delta between current and previous position, AverageAllValues simply adds all values in list and divides by list.Count (aka 30).

This should fix cases when the user move all the way right but a bit up at the end. The last bit should be canceled by the large right movement.

If that is still not enough, then you could add some logic within the method that if a value is too far gone from the average, discard it. I don't think you need this in there.

Comment: I'll try to implement something based on your code. Thanks again fafase!

Comment: Keep in mind that this is asynchronous, so best practice is to pass a method for the result parameter. That method takes the average direction as parameter and could be what you currently have in your Update. The whole point is that while the coroutine is running, no other action concerning input should be taken.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a Queue of positions with limited size right after dragging .

by comparing final value of Queue and first value you can find the direction.

If you want to get better results you can get Variance of positions and get better results.